# Record Persistence in Neo4j.rb 8.0.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, rspec-rails, neo4j.rb

I am in the process of upgrading to Neo4j.rb version 8.  After following the instructions in the [upgrade guide](http://neo4jrb.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.x/UpgradeGuide.html), specs that were passing before are now failing.

Specifically, `count`, `persisted?`, `all`, `last` and `find` seem to have come unhinged from each other.  I can create an account, see that is is persisted, see it if I count accounts, but not if I look for the last account, or all accounts, or try to find it from its id.

Output from console session below.  Am I crazy?

`[1] pry> account = Account.create(company_name: "Acme Corporation, LLC", street_address: "1234 Fake Lane", city: "Pleasantville", state: "CA", zip: "12345", country: "United States", phone: "555-555-5555", contact_name: "Some Guy", contact_phone: "123-456-7890", contact_email: "someguy@acmecorp.com")`

`=> #<Account uuid: "30c44118-ac45-4559-b63b-8e82fafb16cd", city: "Pleasantville", company_name: "Acme Corporation, LLC", contact_email: "someguy@acmecorp.com", contact_name: "Some Guy", contact_phone: "123-456-7890", country: "United States", created_at: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 19:13:52 +0000, phone: "555-555-5555", remote_id: nil, state: "CA", street_address: "1234 Fake Lane", updated_at: Thu, 23 Mar 2017 19:13:52 +0000, zip: "12345">`

`[2] pry> account.persisted?
=> true`

`[3] pry> Account.count
=> 1`

`[4] pry> Account.last
=> nil`

`[5] pry> Account.find(account.id)
Neo4j::ActiveNode::Labels::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Account with 'uuid'=30c44118-ac45-4559-b63b-8e82fafb16cd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is....... RESTART YOUR COMPUTER AND EVERYTHING WORKS!!!111

In reality the problem was that somewhere along the line I deleted the database rather than stopping it, and then installed a new copy.